# find column names and table names referenced in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How to find all the tables and column names used in a SQL? It is on ORACLE database. Below is an SQL  example.

```
SELECT 
   A.ENAME,
   A.AGE as EMP_AGE,
   B.DNAME 
FROM
   emp a,
   dept b
WHERE
   a.deptno= b.deptno
```

I want the output to be like this

```
TABLENAME, COLUMNNAME
EMP, ENAME
EMP, DEPTNO
EMP, AGE
DEPT, DNAME
DEPT, DEPTNO
```

I did some research and failed to find a perfect solution. does it help if we create a view or stored procedure? Please advise.

Comment: What I normally do is in two steps: first `show tables;` and then `describe tble_name(i)` where `tble_name(i)` is the name of the `ith` table listed after `show tables;`.

Comment: You have to query from data dictionary. select * from `USER_TAB_COLS` or `dba_tab_cols` or `all_tab_cols`. [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables014.htm#ADMIN01508)

Comment: There is a 150 lines SQL with many tables, joins , alias etc. I want to find the columns and tables used only in that SQL. Say the emp table has 10 columns and dept table has 8 columns in database. But the SQL is using only 3 columns from emp and 2 columns from dept. How do we figure it ??

Comment: @AttapurBaba. I have a technique, but it's not officially supported. So use at your own risk. However, I'm curious as to what you need this for?

Comment: @MattCremeens Show Tables i not valid Oracle syntax

Comment: I have around 100 SQL reports that i need to analyze forthe fields and tables that are used and the SQL's are very big.I am a lone resource for my company and it will take really long time if i choose to do it manually. :(

Comment: @BobC Anything helps..

Comment: @AttapurBaba What sort of analysis? I'm just trying to make sure you are not going down a path you don't need to...

Comment: @BobC the company i work has a billing source system that is on Oracle db. so far the 100 reports are executed on a Reporting Server db. every month they take a snapshot of the billing system and paste in RS db and execute the reports. However now they choose to implement oracle's OUA product that has end to end prebuilt datamart, reports etc. Now we want to make sure that the 100 existing reports are compatible with the oracle prebuilt data mart. if there are any missing columns or tables then oracle will do an ETL to pull those additional fields.

Comment: For that i need to first identify all the columns and tables used in these SQL's and send it to our vendor ORACLE so that they can compare with their prebuilt available columns and add new if required. see how painful.

Comment: Does your existing reporting system maintain metadata?  Most do (e.g. Discoverer, OBIEE). This seems like the most natural approach to your problem. If you do not have a seeded metadata approach with your reporting system, parsing the active sql (v$sql), filtering by the user attributes might be a good fall back.  Lastly, can you verify your Oracle version? I suspect you are not on 12.2 (e.g. S. Feuerstein's solution).

Answer (score 2):

I have a great solution for you, but there are two things you will need to do:

1. Place the SQL inside a PL/SQL program unit. So, yes, to the stored procedure you mentioned.
2. Compile that program unit and all dependent tables (that is, install your application code) on a 12.2 instance (you can download 12.2 at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html or you can purchase an Exadata Express CLoud Service at cloud.oracle.com or get a $300 credit to use one at no cost for a month at cloud.oracle.com/tryit).

12.2 is key because the feature you REALLY want to use is called PL/Scope and it is a compiler tool that collections information about PL/SQL identifiers (as of 11.1) and SQL usage inside PL/'SQL (as of 12.2).

```
CREATE TABLE my_data (n NUMBER)
/

ALTER SESSION SET plscope_settings='identifiers:all, statements:all'
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_procedure (n_in IN NUMBER)
   AUTHID DEFINER
IS
   l_n           my_data.n%TYPE;

   CURSOR all_data_cur
   IS
          SELECT *
            FROM my_data
      FOR UPDATE OF n;
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO my_data (n)
        VALUES (n_in);

END;
/

  SELECT idt.line,
         idt.owner || '.' || idt.object_name code_unit, 
         idt.name column_name,
         RTRIM (src.text, CHR (10)) text
    FROM all_identifiers idt, all_source src
   WHERE     idt.usage = 'REFERENCE'
         AND idt.TYPE = 'COLUMN'
         AND idt.line = src.line
         AND idt.object_name = src.name
         AND idt.owner = src.owner
         AND idt.object_name = 'MY_PROCEDURE'
ORDER BY code_unit, line
/

LINE CODE_UNIT          COLUMN_NAME TEXT  
4   STEVEN.MY_PROCEDURE N           l_n           my_data.n%TYPE;
10  STEVEN.MY_PROCEDURE N           FOR UPDATE OF n;
12  STEVEN.MY_PROCEDURE N           INSERT INTO my_data (n)
```

Hope that helps!

Lots more examples of PL/Scope at livesql.oracle.com. Just search for "pl/scope" (duh).

Comment: Solution seem to be convincing. I will try and get back. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

What I have realised is that this solution will not give you the projected columns, so it may not totally need you needs; it only gives you the columns used in predicates

```
select
  r.name owner
, o.name tabl 
, c.name colmn
from
sys.col_usage$ u,
sys.obj$ o,
sys.col$ c,
sys.user$ r
where
r.name='&scahme' and
o.obj# = u.obj#
and c.obj# = u.obj#
and c.col# = u.intcol#
and o.owner# = r.user#
```

The execution plan will give you predicate information. For example,

```
SQL> select ename as name, job as junk
  2  from emp
  3  /

 select * from table( dbms_xplan.display_cursor( null, null, 'ADVANCED' ) )

Plan hash value: 3956160932

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |       |       |     2 (100)|          |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMP  |    14 |   196 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - SEL$1 / EMP@SEL$1

Outline Data
-------------

  /*+
      BEGIN_OUTLINE_DATA
      IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS
      OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('12.1.0.2')
      DB_VERSION('12.1.0.2')
      ALL_ROWS
      OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$1")
      FULL(@"SEL$1" "EMP"@"SEL$1")
      END_OUTLINE_DATA
  */

Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):
-----------------------------------------------------------

   1 - "ENAME"[VARCHAR2,10], "JOB"[VARCHAR2,9]
```

Comment: unfortunately most of the SQL's are complex and have lot of subquerys and alias and the final result set column names are always different than the names on the database.

Comment: This report will give you actual column names that are used in predicates. But not the projections. The only thing I can think of is that you generate an execution plan report using the 'ADVANCED" option; this will list out the projected columns. I will update my answer with an example...

Answer (score -1):

If you can convert your query into VIEW and then use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE

Here is an example:

let's say your view name is ABC

then use this one

```
SELECT VIEW_NAME, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME  
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE   VIEW_NAME = 'ABC'
```

Let me know if it works..

Comment: i asked my dba to execute it. it didn't work. got error that Information_schema is invalid. i replaced that with the schema on which we have a test view. didn't work. :(

Comment: I don't think this is valid in Oracle. Is this MariaDB?